# Can I open an URL with its path name by means of another URL host name?

Tags: nginx, dns, server, hosting

I am coding with Django, and using Nginx;
How can I for example open:

> www.example.com/part1/part2

by means of opening:

> www.example2.com

In addition,

> www.example2.com/part3

opens in fact

> www.example.com/part1/part2/part3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register www.example2.com.

In nginx you can listen on that address and return a redirection to www.example.com

```
server {
    listen www.example2.com:80;

    location ~ /(.*)$ {
         return 301 http://www.example.com/part1/part2/$1;
    }
}
```

However, this will change the URL in the address bar. An alternative would be to pass all requests via proxy_pass:

```
server {
    listen www.example2.com:80;

    location ~ /(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com/part1/part2/$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am really newbie; thus, when I type www.example2.com in a browser, the URL will change to http://www.example.com/part1/part2/ or just it will open it without URL changing?

Comment: I just edited my answer with an alternative solution.